# Create Task along with due dates when opportunity stage is changed

Tags: apex, trigger

```
Trigger TaskCreation on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    List<Task> taskToInsert = new list<Task>();
    if(trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
        for(Opportunity opp: trigger.new) {
            if(opp.StageName == 'Prospecting') {
                Task objTask = new Task();
                objTask.whatId = opp.Id;
                objTask.subject = 'Prospecting';
                taskToInsert.add(objTask);
            }
            else if(opp.StageName == 'Qualification') {
                Task objTask = new Task();
                objTask.whatId = opp.Id;
                objTask.subject = 'Qualification';
                taskToInsert.add(objTask);
            }
            else  if(opp.StageName == 'Needs Analysis') {
                Task objTask = new Task();
                objTask.whatId = opp.Id;
                objTask.subject = 'Needs Analysis';
                taskToInsert.add(objTask);
            }
            else if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
                Task objTask = new Task();
                objTask.whatId = opp.Id;
                objTask.subject = 'Closed Won';
                taskToInsert.add(objTask);
            }
            else if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost') {
                Task objTask = new Task();
                objTask.whatId = opp.Id;
                objTask.subject = 'Closed Lost';
                taskToInsert.add(objTask);
            }
        }
        if(!taskToInsert.isEmpty())
            insert taskToInsert ;
    }
}
```

When an opportunity goes into a certain stage, we would like tasks representing the “next steps” to be automatically generated. Requirements include:

1. Tasks should only be auto-generated for records with a record type of National Account
2. All tasks should be assigned to the opportunity owner
3. If the opportunity is moved to the next stage while there are incomplete auto-generated tasks, those open tasks associated with the prior stage should be closed, with a completed date reflecting the same date that the opportunity stage changed.

   a.    Note that tasks that have been manually created by the user should be kept open.

The tasks to be auto-generated for each stage are as follows:

```
Stage                           Tasks
Prospecting               Task Name: Complete Sales Information 
Due Date:                 2 Business Days from Stage Start
Idea Generation           Task Name: Product Sourcing
Due Date:                 3 Business Days from Stage Start

                          Task Name: Send Presentation
Due Date:                 5 Business Daye from Stage Start

                          Task Name: Idea Presentation Follow Up
Due Date:                 8 Business Days from Stage Start

Sample Request            Task Name: Order Samples 
Due Date:                 2 Business Days from Stage Start

                          Task Name: Sample Follow Up
Due Date:                 7 Business Days from Stage Start

Proposal / Price Quote    Send Quote – 5 Business Days from Stage Start
                          Quote Follow Up – 7 Business Days from Stage Start

Negotiation / Review      N/A
Closed Won                N/A
Closed Lost               N/A
```

Comment: Have you tried this already? What challenges you faced?

Comment: I know this can be possible using Triggers. I tried this some what. please see my code

Comment: Have you considered using Process Builder, though? You could implement this requirement without any code at all.

Comment: can you suggest me how to do this using process builder?

Comment: Try [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder) and ask a new question if you run into trouble with it.

Answer (score 1):

You're only considering inserts, not updates, because of this line:

```
if(trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
```

Instead, you'll want to remove that and put the if statement in your for loop (with minor changes):

```
for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
  // On insert or when stage name has changed
  if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).StageName != record.StageName) {
    // rest of code ...
```

Comment: Also suggest me how to add due dates while creating tasks.

Comment: @ish Set the `ActivityDate` field.

Comment: what about business days. can you give the example of any one of the stages?

Comment: @ish You'll want to look at the [`BusinessHours`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) class to calculate days.

Comment: It will be helpful for me if u provide me an example

Comment: @ish, try to avoid changing the scope of existing questions in the comments. Instead, [ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question.